# How to hide git acronym M from Visual Studio code tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just updated VSCode and now am seeing this tab with an M next to the file name: [image]

Anyone know how to remove this acronym from the tab?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the setting that toggles this behavior:
[image]